# If a user has bought my app and I make it a paid app later, do they get updates for free?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've created a Windows Phone app.

It was originally free, however, I then made it a paid for application.

Will the people who downloaded it when it was free receive the new updates for free or will they be forced to buy it?

Thanks for the help; I'm not sure if this is the right section by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every user (free or paid) will receive free updates. Updates are always free.